# White background issue using DEFacebookComposeViewController in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I am using DEFacebookComposeViewController for sharing on Facebook.

I am having issue in one view controller it changes the background color of view to white instead of that transparent black background.[image: White background issue]

Comment: Please note this only happens when I am pushing a viewController on added subview it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. You need to uncomment the code in following file:
"DEFacebookComposeViewController.h"

Just replace the following code:

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  ```
  // Take a snapshot of the current view, and make that our background after our view animates into place.
  // This only works if our orientation is the same as the presenting view.
  // If they don't match, just display the gray background.
    if (self.interfaceOrientation == self.fromViewController.interfaceOrientation) {
  //        UIImage *backgroundImage = [self captureScreen];
  //        self.backgroundImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc]               initWithImage:backgroundImage] autorelease];
     }
     else {
     //            self.backgroundImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.fromViewController.view.bounds] autorelease];
  }
        //    self.backgroundImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
  //    self.backgroundImageView.alpha = 0.0f;
  //    self.backgroundImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
  //    [self.view insertSubview:self.backgroundImageView atIndex:0];

  // Now let's fade in a gradient view over the presenting view.
     self.gradientView = [[[DEFacebookGradientView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.bounds] autorelease];
     self.gradientView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
     self.gradientView.transform = self.fromViewController.view.transform;
     self.gradientView.alpha = 0.0f;
     self.gradientView.center = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.center;
     [self.fromViewController.view addSubview:self.gradientView];
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
               animations:^ {
                   self.gradientView.alpha = 1.0f;
               }];    

     self.previousStatusBarStyle = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle;
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:YES]; 

     [self updateFramesForOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];

        }
  ```

With this code:

```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Take a snapshot of the current view, and make that our background after our view animates into place.
    // This only works if our orientation is the same as the presenting view.
    // If they don't match, just display the gray background.
if (self.interfaceOrientation == self.fromViewController.interfaceOrientation) {
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [self captureScreen];
    self.backgroundImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage] autorelease];
}
else {
    self.backgroundImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.fromViewController.view.bounds] autorelease];
}
self.backgroundImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
self.backgroundImageView.alpha = 0.0f;
self.backgroundImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.view insertSubview:self.backgroundImageView atIndex:0];

    // Now let's fade in a gradient view over the presenting view.
self.gradientView = [[[DEFacebookGradientView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.bounds] autorelease];
self.gradientView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
self.gradientView.transform = self.fromViewController.view.transform;
self.gradientView.alpha = 0.0f;
self.gradientView.center = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.center;
[self.fromViewController.view addSubview:self.gradientView];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                 animations:^ {
                     self.gradientView.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }];    

self.previousStatusBarStyle = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:YES]; 

[self updateFramesForOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];

   }
```

Hope this will help other if they found similar issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No need to make changes anywhere in the code, Just replace this code in implementation module

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

with

```
appDelegate.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

And your work will b done.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. I wish I understood what caused it in the first place.

Comment: Actually that line is wrong. IT is for the viewcontroller inside code.. NOt for external implementation.